# Showing CanCanCan roles in dropdown for roles one can manage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

I have a dropdown for changing the role of a user in my Rails 4.2 app with CanCanCan. The User::ROLES array of strings holds the different possible roles that a user can have. To display the roles in a dropdown:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select((User::ROLES), @user.role) %>
```

I want to limit the dropdown options to roles that the currently signed-in user `can :manage` according to CanCanCan. Roles that the current user does not have `:manage` permissions on should not be populated in the dropdown. Any guidance is appreciated.

edit:

Sean Huber's answer is perfect if comparing against the string literals. However, I realized the issue is that I define this array in my User model, but I need to be comparing against the roles that are set one level deeper in `ability.rb`. Here's an example of how permissions on the User model are set in `ability.rb`:

This makes sense, however I realized it won't really work since it's comparing to the literals in the User::ROLES array.

The code in `ability.rb` that sets roles access looks like this. I need to check against the specific role specified:

```
if user.role? :superadmin
  can :manage, User, role: 'admin'
end
```

How can I compare against the specific roles that the `:superadmin` tokenized role has `:manage` access over instead of the literals in `User::ROLES`?

The definition of ROLES from User.rb:

`ROLES = %w[student teacher school district reseller admin superadmin god]`

Comment: how do you know which roles they can manage?

Comment: @TallPaul roles that users can manage are kept in the `app/models/ability.rb` class. I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: Given your edit, you might want to look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809203/get-a-string-that-represents-a-users-cancan-abilities

Answer (score 0):

Whatever action is being performed in your controller should have some code that sets the `@user` field and a assembles a collection of roles usable by your view. In your case, it's a matter of deciding in the controller method what roles should be included in the collection being passed to the view.

The simplest approach iterates through your roles, tests them using CanCanCan and then adds them to a filtered collection that your `options_for_select` can use.

```
def some_method

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @roles = Array.new

  User::ROLES each do | role |
    if can? :manage role
      @roles.push(role)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line solution:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(User::ROLES.map{|r| can?(:manage, r) ? r : nil}.compact, @user.role) %>
```

Comment: This is perfect but I've updated the original question with an issue with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `take` to solve this:

`<%= f.select :role, options_for_select(User::ROLES.take(User::ROLES.index(current_user.role)), @user.role) %>`

Comment: what does take do?

Comment: grabs the passed number of elements from an array. Here I use it to grab it by using the `current_user.role` as the index. It works because my roles are in ascending order in the `User::ROLES` array. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take